# How to combine Kleisli[M, A, C] and Kleisli[M, B, C]

Tags: scala, functional-programming, scalaz, kleisli

I follow the design of the excellent book *Reactive Domain Modeling* and I need to mix `Kleisli` with different types :

```
object CombinedKleisli {
  type User = String
  type Project = String

  trait UserRepo
  trait ProjectRepo
  trait UserService {
    def findByUserId : Kleisli[Future, UserRepo, User]
  }
  trait ProjectService {
    def findProjectById : Kleisli[Future, ProjectRepo, Project]
  }
  trait ComposedService extends UserService with ProjectService {
    for {
      user <- findByUserId
      project <- findProjectById
    } yield (user, project)
  }

}
```

And as the types don't align, I get the following compilation error

```
Error:(28, 15) type mismatch;
 found   : scalaz.Kleisli[scala.concurrent.Future,domain.service.ServiceTest.ProjectRepo,(domain.service.ServiceTest.User, domain.service.ServiceTest.Project)]
    (which expands to)  scalaz.Kleisli[scala.concurrent.Future,domain.service.ServiceTest.ProjectRepo,(String, String)]
 required: scalaz.Kleisli[scala.concurrent.Future,domain.service.ServiceTest.UserRepo,?]
      project <- findProjectById
              ^
```

What is the best way to fix that, creating a

```
trait Context {
  def userRepo
  def projectRepo
}
```

and pollute `UserService` and `ProjectService` with it ?

Comment: And your question is?

Comment: It might help to post the compiler (type) error you're getting to highlight the problem. @TheArchetypalPaul: The one in the title, presumably.

Comment: @Bergi that's not a very specific question. Yann's been on SO long enough to know how to give the required details

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You'll need to come up with some way to combine the input types into a single type. One way to do this would be inheritance—you'd have a type `UserRepo with ProjectRepo` that is a subclass of both `UserRepo` and `ProjectRepo`. Another way would be composition, where you have a tuple `(UserRepo, ProjectRepo)`.

In both cases you'd generally use `local` to "expand" the input types of each arrow so that you can compose them in the `for`-comprehension:

```
for {
  user <- findByUserId.local[(UserRepo, ProjectRepo)](_._1)
  project <- findProjectById.local[(UserRepo, ProjectRepo)](_._2)
} yield (user, project)
```

Here the `(UserRepo, ProjectRepo)` type parameter argument specifies the new input type and the value argument (e.g. `_._1`) specifies how to get to the original arrow's input type from the new input type.